# How do I associate .pyw files with Python in OSX?

Tags: macos, python, python-gui

A `.pyw` file is a Python script that launches an application with a user interface, without a console window. I want to be able to double click a `.pyw` file in Finder in OSX to open that application, but when I right click and select *Open With*->*Other* I'm not allowed to select `/usr/bin/python`. It is greyed out even though I've enabled "All applications".

I assume this is because it will only let me select `.app` directories. It there any way to work around this so that I can open Python GUI applications without the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Automator to create an application like this:

[image: Automator workflow for pythonw]

(Make sure you select the *as arguments* option in the *Pass input* dropdown.)

The script in `Run Shell Script` above is (notice Pass Input as arguments):

```
/usr/bin/python "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
exit 0
```

When saving it choose File Format Application (not Workflow). You could save it as `/Applications/pythonw`.

Then select a pyw file, press Command-I and select `Open with`>`Other...` and `/Applications/pythonw`. Then click `Change All...` and confirm with OK. The Get Info window should look like this:

[image: Get Info pyw file]

Now double click the pyw file and accept the warning (only the first time).

I've tested it with gui1.pyw:

```
from Tkinter import Label
widget = Label(None, text='Hello GUI world!') 
widget.pack()
widget.mainloop()
```

and worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked great for me on my Macbook Pro.  At first I used get info to associate with python launcher, but it would open up the launcher and terminal windows.  Even when the app was closed the terminal window remained open, a real pain.  This solved all those problems and just my app opens up and closes.  Make sure you select "as arguments" for the pass inputs dropdown.